# Time complexity of KMP algorithm

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to implement strstr using KMP algorithm. This is the algorithm given in wikipedia. The time complexity of KMP algorithm is given as O(n) where n is the size of larger string.

```
vector<int> KMP(string S, string K)
{
    vector<int> T(K.size() + 1, -1);
    vector<int> matches;

    if(K.size() == 0)
    {
        matches.push_back(0);
        return matches;
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= K.size(); i++)
    {
        int pos = T[i - 1];
        while(pos != -1 && K[pos] != K[i - 1]) pos = T[pos];
        T[i] = pos + 1;
    }

    int sp = 0;
    int kp = 0;
    while(sp < S.size())
    {
        while(kp != -1 && (kp == K.size() || K[kp] != S[sp])) kp = T[kp];
        kp++;
        sp++;
        if(kp == K.size()) matches.push_back(sp - K.size());
    }

    return matches;
}
```

I do not understand how the complexity of this algorithm is O(n). Can anybody explain how the complexity of this code is O(n) ?

Comment: What else you think this will be and explain?

Comment: I think populating the array T is O(m^2) and the second part will be O(n*m) where m is the size of the smaller string.

Comment: This may help: [wiki: KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume your worry is that the inner loop in both cases may be executed up to m times per outer loop iteration, leading to the worst-case complexities you mention. In fact, this cannot happen.

Looking at the first loop notice inductively that, since T[] is initialized to -1 we have T[0] < 0, and T[1] < 1, and... you can see that we in fact have T[i] < i, which makes sense because T[i] is a pointer back down the string we are searching for.

Now go to the second nested loop and see that kp is only incremented once per outer loop iteration and the inner while loop can only decrease it. Since kp is bounded below by -1 and starts off at 0, over the whole life of the method, we can execute only one more inner loop iteration, in total, than outer loop iteration, because otherwise kp would end up much smaller than -1. So the second nested loop can cost only a total of O(n).

The first nested loop looks trickier until you notice that pos is read from T[i - 1] at the start of the outer loop and then written as T[i] = pos + 1 at the end, so pos is equivalent to kp in the nested loop we have just analysed and the same argument shows that the cost is at most O(K.size()).